# Can I attach things to containers while flying in creative mode?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

The old shift-click problem - attach a hopper to a chest, or a button to a dispenser, or place a rail on the hopper... on PC you do this by clicking while holding shift. In the midair, you can use shift+space to arrest descent and place your block against a container instead of opening the container.

On PE I found I can do this by entering the sneak mode, when landed. But if I'm building something high in creative mode, levitating as normally in creative mode, the sneak button vanishes. Building a floor to stand on just to be able to crouch becomes seriously cumbersome.

Is there some trick to placing blocks against containers in PE when flying, equivalent to  PC's shift+space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fly down, you sneak, like pressing the sneak button on PC. This means that if you press the down button and tap the object quickly, it will place it as if you were sneaking.